# Android Jitpack CMake build failed

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface, jitpack

I have an android studio project the makes use of

```
externalNativeBuild 
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
```

The project build correctly and when someone else pulls the code it also work correctly.

The issue I am having is. When i try to using Jitpack.IO to pull the release from git hub i get the following issue.

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':****lrecognition:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
 A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:Users******AppDataLocalAndroidSdkcmake3.6.4111459bincmake.exe''
```

If i remove the

```
cmake {
                path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
            }
```

Jitpack works correctly.

I am literally unsure if i am not understanding CMake or begin a noob, Casue I am not referencing a hard code path anywhere.

I really hope someone can assist.